# How can I display asset using a helper function from inside a Vue component?

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I have an app with several Vue.js components. I'd like to display a few image assets inside one of them with the equivalent functionality of a helper function Cdn::asset()

Is there an easy or efficient way to do this? Currently I display all assets this way, because I have a Cdn::asset() helper that provides the correct filepath according to .env configuration.

For media files from the application it isn't a problem to just output the path to the image, but with image assets involved in the design of the site is there a worthwhile way to do this?

Only thing I can think of is outputting a base path from Laravel into Vue based on the Cdn::asset() function.

Comment: Can you please add a simple example of what you want and what you have tried?

Comment: Let's say I have a web app located at http://app.com with assets hosted elsewhere accessible by http://cdn.app.com.

It isn't a problem for me to output the filepaths to these from http://app.com if I'm doing so from Laravel, but if I want to do so from client-side JavaScript I have to pass the base path of the cdn to the user on page load

I'm trying to decide whether I should change the base path altogether or use a JavaScript function to modify the paths on an individual basis.

Comment: But `{{ asset('') }}` will return `app.com`, not `cdn.app.com`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes - I should have been more specific that I use the vinelab/cdn package https://github.com/Vinelab/cdn and output assets using {{Cdn::asset()}}

Comment: So it's not the Laravel `asset()` helper. Please, edit your question to not confuse people who comes here with similar doubts, cause if you are not using this package there are simplest ways to achieve that. Rather, it would not be necessary to use the helper.

Comment: Done. As far as I can see in this situation it comes down to preference. If you'll only be presenting assets from one source, setting the base path would work. If not, then the js function is the way to go. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As soon as I wrote that out, it came to me. Just the following function in the head of the document

```
<script>
    function asset(file) {
        return '{{Cdn::asset('')}}' + file;
    }
</script>
```